# Combobox created dynamically from database (JSF)

Tags: mysql, jsp, jsf, combobox, selectonemenu

I wanted to create in JSF a combobox (selectOneMenu). I want to fill this combobox with all logins from one column from Database (SELECT logins FROM database).

Will be much gratefull from any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your backing bean (YourBean in the example) you should have an array of Strings (or of objects with a getter method that returns the String you want). For instance lets assume you have the following code in your backing bean:

```
private ArrayList<String> logins; // read from DB
private String selectedLogin; // this will hold the selected value

// this method will be called by the JSF framework to get the list
public ArrayList<String> getLogins()
{
   return logins;
}

public String getSelectedLogin()
{
    return selectedLogin;
}


public String setSelectedLogin(String sl)
{
    selectedLogin = sl;
}
```

In you Facelets page, assuming you are on JSF 2.x:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{YourBean.selectedLogin}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{YourBean.logins}" itemLabel="#{l}" itemValue="#{l}" var="l"/>
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

This will create a select menu with all the options in the array. Once the form is submitted the value will be set in the String value of your backing bean.

Comment: I occured 1 little problem. When I use "itemValue="#{l}"" in code, page doesn't load to me, so I skipped it. But without it, beans cannot read selected value and always is null. Do you know what could I do in this case and why page do not want to load with "itemValue"?

Comment: Try to use an array of SelectItem rather than String. It's pretty easy to wrap a String in a SelectItem, in this way you can safely remove both itemLabel and itemValue since JSF will take care of everything.

Comment: Unfortunatelly we had to change our project to JSF 1.2. Do you know how is it possible to do now? Sorry for so much trouble.

Comment: My JSF 1.2 skills are a little rusty but the code should work with minor modifications.